# Is the MPICH Hydra an alternative for MPD?

Tags: ubuntu, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I am a user of `mpd` which come from licensed package.

However, I am trying to clone the machine for increasing my parallel computational scope.
The action give me a problem of alarm clock, which is I guess related to the licence.

My scientific software require an processor management package like `mpd`.

Therefore I am looking from the literature and stumble upon `MPICH Hydra` which is free.

Is that possible to replace `mpd` function with `MPICH HYDRA`? Do they provide the same functions? Are there any drawbacks? Thanks

Comment: Any clues or comments are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to replace MPD with hydra. Hydra is the launcher that's been used by MPICH for a couple of years now.

It probably won't be a straight swap in terms of API, but all of the functionality from MPD should be there with ought the headache of having to set up daemons before launching, etc.